# Amazon.Util.ProfileManager is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-dynamodb

`Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials cred = Amazon.Util.ProfileManager.GetAWSCredentials("user-name");`

The compiler gives the warning that ProfileManager is obsolete:

This class is obsolete and will be removed in the future. Please use the Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.NetSDKcredentialsFile, SharedCredentialsFile or SAMLEndPointManager.

But I couldn't find a suitable answer for this on Amazon's Documentation. Is there any sample code for above classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the NetSDKCredentialsFile and SharedCredentialsFile (these implementing ICredentialProfileSource) have TryGetProfile func :

```
TryGetProfile(string userName, out CredentialProfile)
```

then after you get the CredentialProfile you call :

```
AWSCredentialsFactory.TryGetAWSCredentials (CredentialProfile profile, ICredentialProfileSource source, out AWSCredentials)
```

See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) the full documentation.